# Disable alerts for List or a site in SharePoint2013?

Tags: powershell, ootb

I am having a list in SharePoint2013,i want to disable the Alerts Option in that particular list or Site,can any one give example to disable the alerts by using OOTB or PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable alerts for site with stsadm:

```
stsadm –o setproperty –url "YourSiteURL" –pn alerts-enabled –pv False
```

[Alerts: Stsadm properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262629(v=office.12).aspx)

Or you can try the server side code to disable on list level:

[Disable Alerts from a SharePoint List or Library](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/disable-alerts-from-a-sharepoint-list.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no facility to disable the alerts on a list directly. One option is to write some javascript/jquery which reads the current page/Url to be the list page and disable the Alert setting button in the ribbon.

Another way is to create a new permission level which does not allow user to create alerts and assign it to the list as suggested [here](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/375/Disable-SharePoint-Alerts-on-a-Specific-List.aspx)